# Moon trip in 1969 and temperature

Tags: the-moon

The USA claims to have traveled to the moon in 1969.
BUT...
The temperature on the moon at day is 100 C  and at night is -173 cold. How did the astronauts not die??
How did they survive?

Comment: Question should be addressed to [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon) IMO, as it clearly is from the perspective of a moon-landing doubter.  And that's a link to a related question on Skeptics SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be ask on skeptics SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about astronomy. I'm not sure it's a good fit for Skeptics because it just seems like the OP doesn't understand how temperatures were compensated for in the space program; it's not really challenging a notable claim.

Answer (score 4):

Excessive heat loss during lunar night was not a concern; the astronauts needed sunlight to perform their EVAs. Excessive heat gain during lunar day was a concern, at least initially. Because of these concerns, **all** of the moon landings occurred shortly after lunar dawn.

The first few lunar landings only lasted a couple of days, with the spacecraft lifting off the Moon's surface well before lunar noon. None of the feared consequences of excessive heating arose. The astronauts wore good boots. This enabled longer stays on the surface of the Moon in later Apollo missions. Even so, the practice of landing shortly after lunar dawn continued. Those early morning landings provided excellent relief of the terrain during landing and it provided the opportunity for longer stays on the surface of the Moon.

Answer (score 2):

The astronauts wore temperature controlled and pressurized suits and helmets.

Comment: Vacuum is not a very good heat conductor. Those high and low temps are surface temps. Black body temp of moon is about -2 °C, perfectly livable.